# Substituting whitespaces with %20 in PHP. urlencode and rawurlencode does not work

Tags: php, whitespace, urlencode, url-encoding, rawurl

I'm trying to constitute a URL from a multi-word string:
so I have

```
$str = "my string"
```

and I 'm trying to get :

```
"http mysite.com/search/my%20string"
```

but I could not do it with PHP.

```
urlencode($str) => "my+string"
rawurlencode($str)=>"my string"
```

how can I get `"my%20string"` ?

Thanks for any help !

### P.S.:

Maybe I can do `str_replace(urlencode(),etc);`
but is there an argument for urlencode so that it converts correctly by itself?

### P.S. 2:

Turns out that, as Amal Murali said, `rawurlencode()` WAS doing it, I just didn't see it on the browser, when I hover on the link with my mouse.

But when I check the source code, or click on the link, I see that `rawurlencode();` produces the correct link. (With `%20`'s.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) is what you're looking for. However, if your `Content-Type` is set to `text/html` (which is the default), then you will see the space character instead of the encoded entity.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$str = "my string";
echo rawurlencode($str); // => my%20string
```

Note: I'm not suggesting that you should change the `Content-Type` header in your original script. It's just to show that your `rawurlencode()` call *is* working and to explain why you're not seeing it.

Comment: Thanks! But are there any drawbacks to changing my Content Type header ? My meta tag is this : `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` And converting it to plain text could cause problems? Like social media sharing, printing etc. ?

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: This is just for demonstration. `rawurlencode($str)` actually produces `my%20string`. You're just not seeing it because your browser isn't displaying it. The `Content-Type` header change is just to show it is working.

Comment: hmm. I think I got it. so I will never see "%20" in html content-type ?. Edit: OK OK , now I got it. I can see it in the source code :) Thanks for your help ! Accepting in 5 minutes.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: In your question, you say `but I could not do it with PHP.`, but can you show me how you `echo` the value?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Set URL Base so you can add to it.
$url = "httpmysite.com/search/";
// Set String to search for.
$x = " ";
// Set string to replace with. 
$y = "%20";
//Set string to search.
$z = "my site";
// Concatenate
$url = $url . str_replace($x,$y,$z);
```

I layed it out that way to present each step, but I'd just write a method / function for it.

Actually, given that it is standard now to use "_" or "-" in place of spaces for SEO purposes, I'd just replace %20 with _ or -

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! You are right about SEO. But I don't make search pages indexed. And for your str_replace proposal, I think it will cause more problems because I also have UTF-8 (multibyte) characters in the strings, so I also need to convert them. Native function always better for me :) Thanks again !

Comment: Yeah, if the issue is simply that, the rawurlencode() is the way to go.  Actually as I was typing the other messages came in.  lol

Glad to know it worked out  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see `%20` in your URLs you must use [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode).

You should not mess with the content type, because you risk seeing some browsers getting confused and serving your HTML pages as text (as source), that is with the tags not being interpreted into a proper web page.

Of course if you want to debug your PHP code by outputting the `%20`, you are not going to really see a visible result as the `text/html` encoding will tell your browser to interpret the codes and thus your `%20` will transparently be converted into a space.

The "use plain/text" suggestion is just for debugging purposes so you can really see the `%20` being generated. You will use it to create URLs anyway, so the whole plain vs html encoding won't apply to you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) Yes I do not change any headers now. I debug in the source code.